# node RESTful API model with firebase

Tags: node.js, rest, api, firebase, mongoose

I am trying to create a RESTful API using Node.js, which is to serve for an android application. I am using firebase for my database. I am following a tutorial [tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd#) to create the API. It uses mongoose and has routes, models and controllers defined separately. This looks like a very good separation of concerns and wanted to follow something similar for my code as well. But wanted to know how I can create my model in this case. I am able to read data from firebase.

//my code so far

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require('../../<firebase.json>');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "<path_to_firebase_db",

});

var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref();
var item = ref.child('Item');


item.orderByChild("price").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key + " was " + snapshot.val().price + "$");
});
```

---

// my reference as given in the following link:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var TaskSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    Required: 'Kindly enter the name of the task'
  },
  Created_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  status: {
    type: [{
      type: String,
      enum: ['pending', 'ongoing', 'completed']
    }],
    default: ['pending']
  }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Tasks', TaskSchema);
```

---

I want to create model similar to this, how can I do this? I am new to node and firebase and I have trying to find out some resource for it but have not been successful so far? Or is there another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to do the trick for me at the moment. Could not find any other similar functions like mongoose.model for firebase

```
var item = ref.child('Item');

item.on('value', function(snapshot){
  console.log(snapshot.key);

  exports.getItems = function() {
    //get the required value and export it so as to be accessed from client
    var o = {};
    var key = snapshot.key;
    o[key] = [];
    o[key].push(snapshot.val());

  return o;
  }
});
```